# Get children and subchildren together?

Tags: xpath, python-2.7, lxml, xml.etree

I am using `lxml` library in python and I am working with `xpath`.I have a an xml file example as follows:

```
<Root>
    <Child1 name="child1">
        <Child2 name="child2" />
    </Child1>
    <Child3 name="child3">
        <Child4 name="child4" />
    </Child3>
    <Child5 name="child5" />
</Root>
```

i need to know if there is a way to get all children at once like `child1,child2,child3,child4` at once... currently I am able to get only `child1, child3, child5` using `root.xpath('node()')`

Comment: Try: `'//node()'` (Assuming Child2 is child of Child1 etc ..)

Comment: Are you sure your xml is correct? Using this xpath you should get all childX elements, because they are all on the same hierarchical level. However, the indentation gives the impression that maybe `Child2` and `Child4` are instead nested withing other Child elements.

Comment: You guys are correct...child2 and child4 are nested with parent child nodes...Sorry my mistake while presenting the question.

Comment: @hr_117your suggestion works. Thank you